# resetting Mongoose model cache

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to get mocha's `--watch` option to work. It works fine, until I have to do anything with a mongoose model. Apparently Mongoose keeps some sort of cache, from my understanding, and the error I get has been [tracked and closed](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1251). The problem is, I'm a bit new to this whole thing and need a little guidance how and where to put the things I need to get this to work. So, what I've tried:

- [creating a wrapper around `mongoose.model`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1251#issuecomment-13631313). Works, but obviously defeats the purpose of `--watch`.
- Disconnecting from Mongo (with `mongoose.disconnect`) in the "after" block of my Mongoose suite.
- Giving up on `--watch` and running tests fresh every time.

Of those three, obviously on the third works, and I'd really like to use all the features of my build tools. So, here's what I have. Where am I going wrong?

#### models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    register = require('./_register');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password) {
    this.password = password;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

#### test/models.user.js

```
var User = require('../models/user');

describe('User', function() {

    describe('#setPassword()', function() {
        it('should set the password', function() {
            var user = new User();
            user.setPassword('test');
            user.password.should.not.equal('');
        });
        it('should not be in plaintext');
    });

    describe('#verifyPassword()', function() {
        it('should return true for a valid password');
        it('should return false for an invalid password');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11):

I had some success with running this in my afterEach() block:

```
delete mongoose.models.YourModel;
delete mongoose.modelSchemas.YourModel;
```

Comment: One of the Mongoose developers says this answer should work   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/rx2JmGB7Nr0

Comment: This answer only worked for me if I also added `mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(done);`

Answer (score 0):

To complement boneskull, here is the ES6 code I use including the connection opening/closing to test a `User` mangoose model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import User from '/models/user'

describe('User model', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/somedatabase-test', done)
  })
  afterEach((done) => {
    delete mongoose.models.User
    delete mongoose.modelSchemas.User
    mongoose.connection.close(done)
  })
  ...
})
```